# Declaring a pointer to point to 2-D array pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  int a[5][5];
  int (*p)[5];

  clrscr();

   p=a;
  a[0][0]=5;


  printf("%d\n",p[0][0]);  //This prints 5.

  getch();
}
```

My question is if we want to have a pointer to p itself(double pointer) and then access the elements, then how do we declare it?

Comment: `int (**pp)[5] = &p;` then `printf("%d\n", (*pp)[0][0]);`

Comment: I tried using int a double pointer like int **d =&a[0][0] . Now i am not able to access the elements in the same way like doing with p. In the sense I can't access a with d[0][0]. Can you tell me why?

Comment: `int **d = &a[0][0]` is a type error. `&a[0][0]` is an `int *`.

Comment: Sorry I meant int *d . I mistyped it.

Comment: With `int (*p)[5];`, `p` is _not_ a "pointer to a 2D array".  `p` is a pointer to a 1D array.  With `p=a;` is assigned the value of the address of the first element of `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a 2D array.

```
int a[5][5];
```

`p` is a [pointer to a 2D array](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*p%29%5B5%5D%5B5%5D)

```
int (*p)[5][5] = &a;
```

> if we want to have a pointer to p itself(double pointer) and then access the elements, then how do we declare it?

```
int (**dp)[5][5] = &p;
printf("Value of dp %p\n", (void*) dp);
printf("Value of *dp %p and p %p\n", (void*) *dp, (void*) p);
printf("Value of **dp %p and a %p\n", (void*) **dp, (void*) a);
printf("Value of int array element %d\n", (**dp)[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of where you can use `typedef`

```
typedef int fiveByFiveGrid[5][5];
typedef int (*rowPtr)[5];
typedef rowPtr *rowPtrPtr;

void main()
{
  fiveByFiveGrid a;
  rowPtr p;
  rowPtrPtr pp;

  p=a;
  pp=&p;
  a[0][0]=5;

  printf("%d\n",*pp[0][0]);  //This prints 5.                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

This technique is very valuable if you need very complex declarations. You can use it to build the declarations step by step. Invoking `rowPtrPtr ptr` will be the same as `int (**ptr)[5][5]`